# serialize form and load results with jquery

Tags: jquery, serialization, load

I havent quite found an answer that works for my exact function so here it goes

I wrote a quick function that should send values to an external php file and load the result into a div.. that works fine for 1 form input - what is the best way to get all the form inputs from the form and pass them through the php file and load the results? serialize? how would I implement it??? :)

```
$(function() {  
    function showLoader(){
        $('#results .loader').stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
    }
    //hide loading bar
    function hideLoader(){
        $('#results').fadeIn(1500);
        $('#results .loader').fadeOut(200);
    };
    $('#submit').keydown(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        showLoader();
        $('#results').fadeIn(1500);
        $('#results').load('/patientform.php?val=' + $('#patientSearchForm input').val(), hideLoader());
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      });     
    $('#submit').click(function(){  
        //show the loading bar
        showLoader();
        $('#results .loader').fadeIn(1500);      
        $('#results').load('/patientform.php?val=' + $('#patientSearchForm input').val(), hideLoader());

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to use serialize. But I think a more generic function can be more usefull:

```
function postForm(formId, callback) {
    $(formId).on("submit", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "url/GoesHere",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                // request succeeded
                if (callback) callback.apply(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
               // request error
               alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        return false;
    })
};
```

You can use it to bind the event on every form you want on DOM ready.

Comment: would these cause the page to refresh? it just needs to load into a div :)

Comment: Oh... justo forgot to add a return false.

Answer (score 0):

What about `serialize()`? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Yea I want to use it... but would I be able to keep roughly my same formatting? Would I create a variable that serializes the form and drop it into the load function.. I'm just stuck on the syntax a bit

Answer (score 0):

Where you have you `load()` functions, and you load in your query string, just replace the query string part with this:

```
$('#results').load('/patientform.php?'+$('#patientSearchForm').serialize(), hideLoader);
```

That serializes the form into a query string for submission. Note this won't work with files.

Also, as a note, the second argument in your `load` function shouldn't have the `()` in it. You want to pass the function, not the evaluated value.